# How do you align an image and form side by side, but also center them?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="image">
</div>
<div class="form">
</div>

.image{
  float:left;
}

.form{
  float:left;
}
```

This will put them side-by-side on the left-hand side of the screen. But how can I center them?

Comment: Are they in another div? Or direct children of body?

Answer (score 1):

You must to change all behaviour. First wrap the html like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="form">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    text-align : center;
}
.image, .form {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: This is generally correct, but just note that there would be a whitespace between `.image` and `.form`.

Comment: Oh yeah, but this solved easily putting .wrapper { font-size:0; } and .image, .form {font-size: 100%;}